# Can money received through Google Wallet be easily withdrawn?

Tags: google-wallet

[Google Wallet apparently makes it easy](http://www.google.com/wallet/send-money/) to send money to friends, but it's not clear what can they do with any funds received; there seems to be no mention of any methods for withdrawing the money.

Does this mean received funds need to be spent through a merchant that uses Google Wallet, or can they also be withdrawn (say, to a bank account)?

If so, will this also work for non-US based users? (e.g., I'm in New Zealand)

Answer (score 2):

The money can be withdrawn to a bank account, or left in a Google Wallet account for further use.
Currently, every mention of the new service highlights it supports US residents only. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean received funds need to be spent through a merchant that uses Google Wallet, or can they also be withdrawn (say, to a bank account)?

No. Yes.

[Receive money directly in your bank account. Set a default payment method and any money that’s sent to you will be automatically transferred to that account. No need to manually cash out.](https://www.google.com/wallet/)

> If so, will this also work for non-US based users?

Yes.

[If you're in the US or UK, you can transfer money to people who live in your country. You can't transfer between the US and UK or to people who live in other countries.](https://www.google.com/wallet/faq/)